# Консоль javascript и предпросмотр результата

Tags: javascript

Если открыть консоль разработчика в chrome, и ввести выражение, например `1+1`, то внизу сразу же будет виден результат(не нажимая enter), то же относится и к некоторым простым функциям, например `f = a=>a+1`, при вводе `f(3)` также результат сразу виден. Вопрос, по какому принципу выбирается, для какого выражения будет предпросмотр, а для какого нет? Имел предположение что только для чистых, но для функции `f=a=>a.split('')` он уже не работает, хотя вроде бы чистая функция.

Comment: [Precisely what are the general rules for which expressions results Chrome DevTools' "Eager evaluation" preview text will show?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469338/2881286)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея действительно в том чтобы выводить результат работы чистых функций как можно понять по анонсу введения этой фичи https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-68/#eagerevaluation. Как конкретно v8 решает какие функции можно считать чистыми можно посмотреть в [сорс коде v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c7c447735f762f6d6d0878e229371797845ef4ab/src/debug/debug-evaluate.cc#L313). Алгоритм нетривиальный. Если поискать в файле Add то он числится в списке чистых. Spilt не числится (есть только regexsplit но это другое)